# Reference a resource from another resource

Tags: android, android-resources

quick question my SO/documentation-checking has failed to answer:

Is it possible to have the value of a string-array resource be a reference to another string-array resource?

For instance, say I have an array like this

```
<string-array
android:name="names">
    <item>Danny</item>
    <item>Trevor></item>
    <item>Garth</item>
</string-array>
```

is there some way to get the effect implied by this:

```
<string-array
android:name="appellations"
android:value="@string-array/names" / >
```

such that, say, 
    getStringArray(R.array.appellations)
returns the "names" array?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? That's unnecessary nesting and afaik not even possible. Just call getStringArray(R.array.names) and get rid of the 2nd array.

Comment: In this case, because the name by which I'm referencing the array will change.  Nowhere in the code do I actually call R.array.names; rather, I'm calling 

    getStringArray(getIdentifier(name,array,this.getPackageName()));

where name is a string selected by a user.  

In this case the user is navigating a data hierarchy (a restaurant menu), and I'd like to leave as much data-specific information as possible in the xml, rather than in the code.  If there's a cleaner way to achieve this, I'm all ears.  Thanks.